# Consumo dados no Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, mobile, download, firebase-database

Estou com uma dúvida que está me deixando encucado, e não consegui achar a resposta.

No Android, quando estamos fazendo um aplicativo, normalmente **há várias chamadas para coletar "os mesmos" dados do FireBase**. Por exemplo, abra a aba de clientes: faz a chamada para a listagem de clientes. O usuário abre novamente a activity, há nova chamada para coletar estes dados e exibir em um recycler view (por exemplo!).

**A cada chamada desta gasta-se mais "download"?** Por exemplo, se o usuário acessar várias vezes este activity, cada vez que acessar irá consumir mais download? Ou ele pega de algum cache?

Pelo meus testes... não consegui chegar a uma conclusão.

Se de fato gasta mais "download", alguma sugestão de como contornar esta questão?

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço bastante!

**Obs: Quando vc vai no console do firebase->database->uso tem o termo "Downloads", é disto que estou me referindo.**

Comment: Largura de banda não tem nada a ver com quantidade de dados trafegados. Você pode encher um balde (quantidade de dados) com um conta-gotas (pouca largura de banda) ou com um caminhão pipa (bastante largura de banda). O que muda é o tempo do procedimento.

Comment: Ok, vou corrigir a terminologia.

Comment: Não deu pra entender bem a pergunta, mas setando a persistência do firebase os últimos dados baixados ficam em cache no app, só baixando novos dados